# git pull requests -- Should new PR be created, if old PR is not accepted

Tags: github, gitlab

I am having some lack of clarity on how to handle PR /MR process workflow..

Let us say, I am creating a feature branch in github or gitlab and submitting a PR/MR to my reviewer.

Assuming that my PR is not accepted (the reviewer has given comments that I need to resolve), should he/she close the PR, and subsequently, do I have to raise another PR for this feature branch?

OR,

Shoud I ask my reviewer to re-review the latest version of my feature branch (because it has new commits) and thus merge it?

Comment: I believe that you should leave the PR open, work on the requested changes and push to your branch. The PR should be updated and any CIs should run against the new commits. The reviewer should then check again the PR (might be notified from your push...). Raising a new request will make you loose the review history (if the 2 PRs are not linked somehow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add new commits addressing the reviewer's concerns. The reviewer, if they have notifications on, will be e-mailed everytime you make new changes. Their old comments will then be invalidated (they'll be hidden from view in Github) if the commit changed the part of the file they commented on. They can then continue to review the new code, rinse repeat. There is no need to create a new PR.

Other notes:

- Don't dismiss a review when you make new changes. Dismissing is generally used for when coworkers are on vacation or otherwise unable to review the new changes
- Closing a PR temporarily is usually done to clean up the PR list, but it can be reopened later if your PR is in a reviewable state
- Some teams prefer you create a new PR if the changes are radically different (i.e, your current approach isn't working and you should start from scratch)